# Replacement for 'sum_range' in SUMIFS formula that can match automatically with source data header

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Need your help, through SUMIFS formula, I need the result to be like the one in D5 column. From the formula box in picture, we can see that I wanted to know the ad cost between July 6 to July 8 which data is referred from table range of G4:K7 and the date-range is referred from cells range C1:C2

I need the formula of 'H5:H7' (in yellow) like stated in the formula box in below picture to be replaced, in order to be automatically detected (as far as I know we have to use INDEX & MATCH formula to replace the 'H5:H7').

So then, say, when I make the formula for D6 column, I don't need to change **H5:H7** (in yellow at formula box below) into **I5:I7** manually anymore to refer the 'Revenue' in I5:I7.

I have tried something like:

**(index((H5:K7),,match(C5,(H4:K4),0)** to replace **H5:H7** in yellow below but it didn't work.
What should be the replacement formula for **H5:H7** instead of the one I've tried already in above?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you're just missing some absolute referencing? =SUMIFS(INDEX(H$5:K$7,,MATCH(C5,H$4:K$4,0)),G$5:G$7,">="&C$1,G$5:G$7,"<="&C$2) in D5 and copied down should give you what you want.

Comment: Do you want to get the result as shown? https://imgur.com/a/hBoEqPr Try this formula: **=SUM(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C5,$4:$4,0)),3),"$","")&SUMPRODUCT(($G$4:$K$7=$C$1)*ROW($4:$7))&":"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(C5,$4:$4,0)),3),"$","")&SUMPRODUCT(($G$4:$K$7=$C$2)*ROW($4:$7))))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*Write this Array in Cell `B67` finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` and fill down.*

```
=IF(AND($C$68:$C$70>=$A$64,$C$68:$C$70<=$A$65),SUM(INDEX($D$68:$G$70,,MATCH(A67,$D$67:$G$67,0))),"")
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @freakyholic keep asking ,, ☺